# Need two div's to line up correctly

Tags: html, css, positioning

[Here is a screenshot of how both div's lineup](http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/1425/picture2ye4.png).

The left column is , the div that I want to line up to the right of it is

And both those div's are within

```
.content-body {
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-family:arial;
    overflow:auto;
}

.col-left {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
}

.col-middle {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    xmargin-top:5px;
    xfont-size:.8em;
    border:1px solid red;
    font-family:arial;
}
```

How would I get the .col-middle div to line up properly?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the width of *.col-middle* to *80% or less* so both divs can fit inside their container.

You could also make *.col-middle* float *right*.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (although you really should give the right column a width as well):

```
    .col-middle {
        ...
        margin-left: 20%;
    }
```

**Edit:** If you give .col-middle a left margin, there´s no need to float it or to give it a width

Answer (score 1):

adding a

```
clear:none;
```

to both you column divs

and a

```
width:80%;
```

to your middle column should enable them to go side by side :)

Answer (score 0):

col-middle is taking the width: 100%, so you have to provide the width: less than 80%.

another solution you can do is make the width:79% and remove the float:left and make it display: table-cell;

```
.col-middle {
  width: 79%
  height:auto;
  display: table-cell;
  xmargin-top:5px;
  xfont-size:.8em;
  border:1px solid red;
  font-family:arial;
}
```